# Getting error "Actions must be plain objects" when testing Redux Store with Jest in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test my **Component** function that uses the store.
and I got this error: `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`
for this line inside the component `this.store.dispatch(obj);`

Here is my code:

```js
    onChartClicked(event: ChartData) {
        const classFilters: string[] = ['OT', 'IT', 'IoT'];
        if (event.value !== undefined && event.name) {
            filters.push(createFilter('class_type', [key]));
            console.warn("test1", obj);
            this.store.dispatch(obj);
        }
```

with this **Jest test**

```js
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStoreFactory = configureStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStoreFactory([]);
let comp: DashboardDiscoverAssetsWidgetComponent;
describe('select_actions', () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardDiscoverAssetsWidgetComponent);
        comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        comp.dashboardFilters = {timeframe: String(new Date())};

    test('Dispatches the correct action and payload', () => {
        const eventValue = {value: 2, name: 'IT'};
        comp.onChartClicked(eventValue);
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
});
```

and the error output:

```
    console.warn src/app/ranger/dashboard/components/widgets/dashboard-discover-assets-widget/dashboard-discover-assets-widget.component.ts:99
      test1 SetFiltersAction {
        type: '[Filtered List] set filters',
        payload: {
          listKey: 'RANGER_ASSETS_LIST',
          filters: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
          clearPrevious: true
        }
      }

  ● select_actions › Dispatches the correct action and payload

    Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

Comment: If something isn't clear please comment and I will edit..

Comment: small advice: could you emphasize that your `console.log` displays your action is indeed an `Object` instance. To much code by now, so it's not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time and looking into redux-mock-store source, it appears they check if something is a plain object with this lodash function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isPlainObject

and for some reason they consider this object as not plain [maybe because of typescript]:

```
SetFiltersAction {
        type: '[Filtered List] set filters',
        payload: {
          listKey: 'RANGER_ASSETS_LIST',
          filters: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
          clearPrevious: true
        }
      }
```

so my solution was this:

```js
const tmpDispatch = comp.store.dispatch;
comp.store.dispatch = function(obj) { tmpDispatch({...obj}); };
```

and I will open issue for redux-mock-store